# Is it possible to use different line-height for two or more inline blocks?

Tags: css

Is it possible to use different line-height for two or more inline blocks?
Example:

```css
.block{
  width: 300px;
}

.text-1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 30px
}

.text-2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 15px
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <span class="text-1">Here some text here some text</span>
  <span class="text-2">other text other text other text</span>
</div>
```

This is what I would like to get: 
[image]

Comment: Output does not match to your code

Comment: @Ashish sah do you mean image doesn't match output? :)

Comment: You are in fact using two inline elements with two different line heights. If you are not seeing what you want its because your `width` on `.block` needs to be modified. What is the actual question?

Comment: Ya image is diffrent...its not the output of the code their...

Answer (score -1):

```css
.text-1 {
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.text-2 {
  line-height: 1em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #555;
}

div{
    width: 400px;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-color: #000;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="text-1">Here some text here some text</span>
  <span class="text-2">other text other text other text other text other text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I have solution.
You need to set line-height on parent block (minimum), then you can change any line-height on children. You can not put it lower than that of the parent — that's was my problem :)